# difference between clear list and list = []

Tags: python, scripting

I'm currently getting into some scripts a colleague wrote before and I need them for my bachelor thesis.

When I wrote another script I had the following issue:

```
  listA = [......] #list is filled
  listB = listA
  listB.clear()
```

After this listA was also cleared, which I got around using:

```
  listB = listA.copy()
```

My colleague in her code did this

```
 listA = [.......] #list is filled
 listB = listA
     functoin(listB)
 listB = []
```

After that she still uses listA in a way that it has never been made empty. But since python copys by reference wouldnt mean the command:

```
 listB = []
```

that also listA is empty now?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `listB = []` makes the name `listB` point to a new empty list object. It's not linked to `listA` after that.

Comment: The "my colleague" code is not valid Python.

Comment: If you want a new empty list, why do you assign `listB = listA` **at all**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, when you run your colleagues' code the following happens:

```
listA = [.......] # listA points to a list

listB = listA     # listB and listA are now 2 variables pointing to the SAME OBJECT

function(listB)   # this does the same as function(listA) would do
                  # only the object matters here, the function does not know the variable name

listB = []        # now listB points to a new object, an empty list.
                  # listA and the object to which it points remain the same
```